# Android: Manual DNS cache entry creation

Tags: android, dns

I am working in a lab environment that does not yet have access to a DNS Resolver. I would like to manually configure a few DNS entries on my Android device. I don't seem to see a hosts file on the device, so I am wondering if there is someplace else I should be looking on the device to setup a few entries ??? My device is running Android 2.2 and not rooted.

thanks in advance for any help.

-wk

Answer (score 0):

Too bad it's not rooted, or you could edit `/system/etc/hosts`.

From this issue, it looks as though Android caches lookups for ten minutes, and there is no way to clear the cache.

[Android DNS Caching Issue #7904](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7904)